# Как исключить пост из нужной мне страницы WP

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, как можно исключить категорию постов из нужной мне страницы на WP. Проблема в том, что в интернете есть решения, но они в основном связаны с главной страницей сайта. Есть сайт https://fsledokol.ru и со страницы https://fsledokol.ru/baza-dannyh/trenera/ , мне нужно исключить некоторые категории, для того чтобы убрать посты с главной страницы я использовал код:

```
function removeFromHome($query) { 
    if ($query->is_home) {$query->set('cat','-22,-24,-23');
    } return $query;   
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','removeFromHome');
```

Как должен выглядеть код для вышеуказанной страницы?

Comment: На статической странице не выводятся посты. Как ты их туда поместил - тебе должно быть виднее. И вот тут уже править этот код.

Comment: Хорошо понял. Случайно не подскажите, что делать если в мобильной версии на главной странице отображаются посты, скрытые в десктопной?